# Lucene Indexing/Query strategy for hyphenated words

Tags: java, search, lucene

There are many words which are hyphenated or whitespace separated but often used as one word.
Eg : Basket Ball  or  basket-ball can be written as basketball.

Now when i index as sentence, say :  `"Hey dude, I played basket ball yesterday".`
Now i try to query `"basketball"` [without double quotes]..

This case, or in the vice versa case, (index `basketball` and query `basket ball`) I will not get any results. Is there any way to solve this problem directly or indirectly ?

`Edit:`
I gave the example to just to demonstarte the problem. In my actual application scenario, i'll be indexing and searching IDs. 
If i index : 011 12345,
I should be able to query it using 01112345.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your IDs/phone numbers stored in a separate field or they just occur in text?

Comment: there's no point illustrating your question with an example that bears little relation to your problem, as it means any answers will not necessarily focus on what you are _actually_ trying to do. In future demonstrate the problem with a realistic scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Hyphens are not the issue here, assuming you are using something like the StandardTokenizer that splits on tokens such as hyphens, then users searching for "basket ball" will match the original text "Basket-Ball" (and vica-versa), so no problem there.

The issue is going between two word and one word equivalents, e.g. "basketball" and "basket ball".  You basically need to handle **synonyms** (e.g. jacket/coat  or in your case basketball/ 'basket ball').

You can overcome this by creating a list of equivalent words yourself, or using a dictionary like [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), and supplementing either the index or the search with the synonyms for each term. Solr has a [SynonymFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter) you can probably leverage (also see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory)).

EDIT:

Here's the code for a very basic synonym filter I wrote a while ago. The synonyms are not externalized, but you an easily add that yourself.

```
public class SynonymFilter extends TokenFilter {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SynonymFilter.class);

    private Stack<Token> synStack = new Stack<Token>();

    static CharArrayMap<String[]> synLookup = new CharArrayMap<String[]>(5, true);
    static {
        synLookup.put("basketball".toCharArray(), new String[]{"basket ball"});
        synLookup.put("trainer".toCharArray(), new String[]{"sneaker"});
        synLookup.put("burger".toCharArray(), new String[]{"hamburger"});
        synLookup.put("bike".toCharArray(), new String[]{"bicycle", "cycle"});
    }

    // TODO reverse map all the syns to each other e.g. sneaker to trainer

    protected SynonymFilter(TokenStream input) {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public Token next(Token reusableToken) throws IOException {
        if (synStack.size() > 0)
            return synStack.pop();

        Token nextToken = input.next(reusableToken);
        if (nextToken != null) {
            addSynonyms(nextToken);
        }

        return nextToken;
    }

    private void addSynonyms(Token nextToken) {
        char[] word = Arrays.copyOf(nextToken.termBuffer(), nextToken.termLength());
        String[] synonyms = synLookup.get(word);
        if (synonyms != null) {
            for (String s : synonyms) {
                if (!equals(word, s)) {
                    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
                    Token synToken = new Token(chars, 0, chars.length, nextToken.startOffset(),  nextToken.endOffset());
                    synToken.setPositionIncrement(0);
                    synStack.add(synToken);
                    log.info("Found synonym: " + s + " for: " + new String(nextToken.term()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static boolean equals(char[] word, String subString) {
    return equals(word, word.length, subString);
}

public static boolean equals(char[] word, int len, String subString) {

    if (len != subString.length())
        return false;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < subString.length(); i++) {
        if (word[len - i - 1] != subString.charAt(subString.length() - i - 1))
            return false;
    }

    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: @user326729 and @Joel  

In my actual application scenario, i'm not searching sentences. I'm searching some Id. Eg.Phone number. You never know how people write phone numbers. like 011 12345, 01112345, 011-12345, 011 123 45.

Comment: well then if it's an id strip out all the white space before indexing and querying.

Comment: @raj - The solution is probably that your Analyzer bring all forms of these phone numbers to a common one, say by first removing white space and hyphens and then concatenating digits to get to the longest possible contiguous number. This is doable in Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Lucene user but here are my 2 cents : Before starting indexing you have to preprocess your data to make it look like the way you want to search it. Do you also want it to appear in the search result if someone searches for just ball? If yes then you have to make two sentences as input made from this single sentence("hey dude, I played basket ball yesterday" & "hey dude, I played basketball yesterday") and index both of them. Is this what you are looking for?